# Why is there less latency and jitter when there is additional high bandwidth traffic between two computers with Ubuntu 22.04 installed on them?

Tags: networking, kernel, 22.04, nic, sockets

I have two computers that are connected via an Ethernet cable with Ubuntu 22.04 installed on them. I have a client on computer A) which is sending UDP packets to a server on computer B) and I am measuring the latency and jitter of these packets in different scenarios. I have written the source code of the client and server in C, using the socket library.

When there is additional, high bandwidth traffic between the two computers on top of the packets which latency is measured, the jitter and latency is less than when I send the packets without that additional traffic:

- Round trip time without additional traffic: 0.556 ms
- Round trip time with additional traffic: 0.105 ms
- Jitter without additional traffic: 0.042 ms
- Jitter with additional traffic: 0.014 ms

It seems interesting because I would imagine less packets means less latency and jitter, but the results show otherwise. Can someone tell me what can be the reason? I suspect it has to do with buffer optimization, when more packets arrive, the buffer must be emptied more often but I am not sure. If that is the case, how could I configure the buffers in order to minimize latency?

Comment: Try testing as a function of disabling idle states and as a function of CPU frequency scaling governor. `grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpuidle/state*/disable` , watch your processor temperature as you get to no enabled idle states, as it'll get warm. `grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor`, if not performance already try it. What are the processor make and models on each computer?

Comment: It is all about power saving features of CPU and/or NIC.

Comment: By the way: I would be very interested in the results of the tests I mentioned.